# Human gehaltene Tiere

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es ein Schlagwort, das die „artgerechte“ Haltung von Schlachttieren auf Etiketten kennzeichnet, die Kunden auch bei Labels wie „Bio“ oder „Öko“ erwarten würden? Der Unterschied zu letzteren bestünde vor allem in der Wahl des Futters.

Kürzlich habe ich im Supermarkt Informationen zur „Initiative Tierwohl“ gesehen, deren erklärtes Ziel die Verbesserung der Aufzuchtbedingungen ist. Annähernd antonyme Schlagworte wären „Massentierhaltung“, „Tierquälerei“ und „konventionelle“ oder „industrielle Fleischproduktion“. Das Äquivalent bei Menschen wäre „humane Behandlung“.

Es sollte ein Adjektiv oder anderes Attribut sein, das man in einem Satz wie dem folgenden verwenden kann:

- *Ich kaufe nur noch **…** Fleisch.* vgl.:
- *Ich kaufe nur noch [ethisch] unbedenkliches Fleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch Bio-Fleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch Öko-Fleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch QS-Fleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch Qualitätsfleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch „Tierwohl“-Fleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch ?nachhaltiges Fleisch.*

Mit *artgerecht* müsste man etwas umständlicher formulieren:

- *Ich kaufe nur noch Fleisch aus artgerechter Haltung.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch artgerecht produziertes Fleisch.*
- *Ich kaufe nur noch *artgerechtes Fleisch.*

Comment: Ich glaube, ich fände es gut, wenn sich dafür etwas wie _*Etho-Fleisch_ etablieren ließe, falls es nicht bereits etwas besseres gibt,  wobei das sehr nach _Ethno_ klingt.

Comment: Das Problem bei "artgerechter" Haltung ist, dass jemand das Wort "artgerecht" definieren muesste. Es koennte durchaus sein, dass deine persoenliche Vorstellung was artgerecht ist von der Vorstellung der entsprechenden Behoerde abweicht. Daher waere statt so eines schwammigen Begriffs ein Guetesiegel, aehnlich Stiftung Warentest (zB von besagter Initiative), sinnvoll, wo sich genau nachvollziehen laesst, was hier unter "artgerecht" zu verstehen ist. Beachte auch, dass die aktuelle Tierhaltung "artgerecht" ist, da sie den Vorschriften entspricht. (ja, die Vorschriften sind ggf. nicht ideal...)

Comment: **Wild-**. Zufütterung gibt's da auch, so dass man durchaus von "Haltung" im Wald sprechen kann.

Comment: Interessante Überschrift. Welche Tierart wäre wohl mit Sofa, Bier und Fernseher einverstanden?

Comment: Das sind auch viele Menschen nicht.

Comment: ich würde mich über den Begriff leidfrei freuen, aber das wird man wohl nie umsetzen können

Comment: *Ich kaufe nur noch artgerechtes Fleisch* ist eigentlich sinnlos, aber trotzdem aktuell (Rindfleisch aus Pferden ist definitiv nicht "artgerecht")

Answer (score 3):

*Artgerecht* ist pure Definitionssache - Das kann gehen von "Futter, Wasser, Dach und minimaler Platz zum Leben" (Hühnerhof) bis "imitierte natürliche Umgebung" wie in einem modernen Zoo. Das "Minimum" dürfte möglicherweise nicht deinem Anspruch an "human" genügen. Leider ist "artgerecht" auch schon zu überstrapaziert, so dass die meisten Leute "absolutes Minimum" annehmen dürften.

"Human" impliziert für mich irgendwie (auch) "Meine Schweine dürfen auf dem Sofa sitzen und fahren jedes Jahr zweimal in Urlaub" (also eine für Menschen geeignete Umgebung). Passt nicht gut.

Ein einfaches Ein-Wort-Attribut fällt mir dazu nicht ein, außer vielleicht "*anständig* gehalten", dass ich mir als Aussage unter Fachmännern durchaus vorstellen kann: "Der xxx hält seine Schweine wirklich noch anständig". Aber, was "anständig" ist, dürfte auch einen weiten Definitionsbereich haben.

Ohne eine genauere Beschreibung, was denn die spezifischen Umstände sind, wirst du wohl nicht auskommen. Außerdem ist die persönliche Auffassung des Adressaten sehr unterschiedlich - Manche Leute dürften schon aufschreien, wenn man bei der Tierhaltung nur von "Lebensmittel*produktion*" spricht, andere sagen "Hauptsache billig".

Answer (score 2):

Recht etabliert, wenn auch fast nur im Bereich des informellen Sprechens (und manchmal auch im Bereich des uneigentlichen) ist doch

> Eier von glücklichen Hühnern
>
> Milch von glücklichen Kühen
>
> Wurst aus glücklichen Schweinen

(Na gut. Fleisch von glücklichen Schweinen. "Wurst aus..." habe ich selbst noch nicht gehört)

Aber sieht man mal davon ab, dass man hier auf einem stark ins Ironische neigenden Gelände wandelt: Eigentlich versteht jeder umstandslos, was gemeint ist.

Jetzt aber bitte keine Debatte darüber, ob die im Menschenhirn herumgeisternde Idee des Glücks auf Hühnerhirne übertragbar ist. Der Sinn der "glücklichen Hühner" ist doch, wenn sie selbst ihre Lage erkennen und kommentieren könnten, dass sie gackern würden: "Doch, doch, eigentlich sind wir ganz zufrieden so. Es fehlt uns an nichts. Wir sind happy."

Oder um Herrn Kant mal wieder die Ehre zu geben: Hältst du Hühner, so halte sie so, dass dein Hühnerhalten stets zum allgemeinen Prinzip des Hühnerhaltens gemacht werden könnte.

Comment: Für einen Werbespot ist das geeignet. Für eine seriöse Aussage - wohl eher nicht.

Comment: Vielleicht ist es für einen Werbetext schon nicht mehr geeignet, weil es inzwischen überwiegend ironisch gebraucht wird. Dies jedenfalls in meiner persönlichen Deutschsprechumgebung. Ich gebe aber zu, dass ich damit meinem eigenen Vorschlag, diese Ausdrücke zu verwenden, widerspreche.